# My migration is done but database not showing Users table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add migration and update database it shows result done but actually database is not showing table Users

```
// Models Class Users 
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace OBT.Core.Models
    {
        public class Users
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**UsersConfigurationClass**

```
namespace OBT.Repository.Configurations
    {
        internal class UsersConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Users>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Users> builder)
            {
                builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
                builder.Property(x => x.UserId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
                builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(30);
                builder.Property(x => x.Email).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(200);
                builder.Property(x => x.MobileNumber).HasMaxLength(30);
                builder.Property(x => x.Password).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(200);




            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic). Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Comment: Do other entities work? I so, what are the differences between them and `Users`? What did the migration do, have you checked? With no info about the migration is hard to know what did happen.

Comment: I created Users Class at first that time database created successfully but after that i remove migration for users and again add that then it doesnt create any table

Comment: @Sagar You may also need to delete that removed migration entry from the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table and then try running the migration again